# Office 365 document library remote event receiver issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, remote-event-receiver

`ItemAdded` event issue:

Whenever we upload Office documents (Excel, Word and PowerPoint), the first time, it hits and works fine. If we upload the same document and replace, then the event is not firing. Except Office files, the event is working as expected (text, zip, csv, etc.).

Please let me know the fix for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems by design, if you upload same office documents, SharePoint check the document exists or not, then replace it. The ItemUpdated event will fire and ItemAdded event will not fire.

So, you can add some logic in ItemUpdated event to achieve your requirement.